# Switch music apps depending on bluetooth connection (car/headphones)

Tags: bluetooth, google-play-music, default-applications, bluetooth-audio, bluetooth-pairing

To start, I have a 2016 Mazda CX-5 and a Galaxy S7. Google Music works best in my car because for whatever reason because I am able to view the "Root" menu and explore artists, songs, playlists, etc. When Poweramp is running, I get a message that says "unable to view the content of this device."

For my other bluetooth audio (headphones, soundbar, etc.), I prefer to use Poweramp over Google Music.

My question is: Is there an app that can recognize my bluetooth connection and default to a specific music player? i.e When I get into my car, my S7 connects and Google Music is auotmatically defaulted to. When I pair my S7 with my gym headphones, Poweramp is automatically defaulted to.

My purpose is that I would normally use iSyncr + Poweramp full time to manage my audio, but I HAVE to use Google Music in my car to be able to view that "Root" menu unless anyone has had success with another music app.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix.

The app **Macrodroid** allows the user to create very simple but effective logic in automating which app is opened depending on what Bluetooth device is connected.

Also, after trying a plethora of music apps (Poweramp, PlayerPro, RocketPlayer) I found that **Samsung Music** allows my car to display all folders appropriately. I also found that Samsung Music stores the music quite simply and has a great EQ to boost quality.

I still use **iSyncr** to send playlists to the /Music/ folder on my SD card. So in short a combination of:

```
iSyncr + Macrodroid + Samsung Music
```

allows me to seamlessly control where and how my music is played.